# asp.net objectdatasource pass parameter from control as well as textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, textbox, objectdatasource

I have configured a `GridView` to fill data by an `ObjectDataSource`. This `ObjectDataSource` requires only one parameter which is bound to a `DropDownList`. This all works well.

When i load the page, it fills the `DropDownList` and whatever field is displayed in this `DropDownList`is passed as a parameter to the `ObjectDataSource` which further fills the `GridView`.

Now, i want to enhance the functionality and have a `TextBox` and `Button` next to this `DropDownList`. I want to give my user the option to either select a value from the `DropDownList`, OR TYPE IT IN THE `TextBox` AND PRESS ENTER TO UPDATE THE `GridView`.

Any idea how to do it?

I have tried `dataSource.Selecting` event. but it isn't working the way i want it to be.
please help

Comment: Parameter will always the same from either of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rough sample but basically what you can do is instead of creating a control parameter you can create a session parameter or something similar:

So when you click enter it will use the textbox value or when you change the dropdownlist it will use the dropdownlist's value.

You can also have radio button's giving the user the option to specify from where he want's the value.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="ClickMe" ID="btnOne" OnClick="btnOne_Click"/>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="ObjectParameterName" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        Session["ObjectParameterName"] = ddl.SelectedValue;
        ObjectDataSource1.Select();
    }

    protected void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        Session["ObjectParameterName"] = txt.Text;
        ObjectDataSource1.Select();
    }
```

**EDIT AFTERTHOUGHT**

You can also instead of assigning the parameter to a session field, just set the objectdatasource's parameter directly (Barring Exception handling).

```
    protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter() {Name="Name",DefaultValue=ddl.SelectedValue });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you TBohnen, what i actually did was used your Logic and got the idea, I added dropdownlist_selectedindexchanged event ... and whenever the event is triggered, i take the parameter value from dropdownlist.selectedvalue... 
and if the button is clicked, i use the code given by Muhammad Akhtar.. What exactly i was missing was that i wasn't clearing the value of selectParameter before adding a new parameter.... However, i solved my problem....Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is the `SelectParameters.Add` method which takes the ColumnName and value as a parameter to pass in the parameter value.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ods.SelectParameters.Clear();
  ods.SelectParameters.Add("ColumnName", SetparameterValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Akhtar bhai, what i actually did was used your code, and added dropdownlist_selectedindexchanged event ... and whenever the event is triggered, i take the parameter value from dropdownlist.selectedvalue... and if the button is clicked, i used your code... Thanks a lot